# Unable to close screen after the email attachment download is completed

Tags: blackberry

I am using `AttachmentDownloadManager` class download method to download the email attachments to the device.I am displaying a progress screen while the attachments gets downloaded to device.In the `downloadCompleted()` event listener method, I am trying to stop/close the progress screen but unable to do so.
Below is the code snippet:

```
 attachmentDownloadMngr = new AttachmentDownloadManager();
 attachmentDownloadMngr.download(attachmentBodyPart, null, new IGAEmailAttachmentListener(this));
```

Below are `DownloadProgressListener` event listener methods:

```
public void updateProgress(Object element, int current, int total)
{
   synchronized(UiApplication.getEventLock())
           {
                Ui.getUiEngine().pushGlobalScreen(progressScreen,1,UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);                  

           }
}


public void downloadCompleted(Object element)
{
synchronized(UiApplication.getEventLock())
           {
              Ui.getUiEngine().popScreen(progressScreen);
}
}

public void downloadCancelled(Object element)
{
}
```

`progressScreen` is instance of `PopupScreen` where I am displaying a `guagefield`. The progress screen does not get any events even after the attachment download is completed.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you try popScreen.close() instead?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be pushing a globalscreen every time you get a callback to `updateprogress()` . I wouldn't do it. I would rather push the `globalscreen` with the `gaugefield` when I start the download, and then set the value of gaugefield using `gaugeField.setValue(value)`.

the way you are doing it would mean, the event thread pushes too many screens on to the stack, and I guess it would throw a run time exception and kill your app.

Comment: Hi Rishan, thanks for your reply. I did the same but still the same issue. I am checking for progress screen is null initially and pushing global screen else updating the guage field using setValue method. But still i m facing the same issue.